# Spring data with MongoDB Views

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-jpa

To improve our query performances and hence the API response times, we created views on MongoDB by aggregating the data. However when we try to use the view using Spring Mongo template, running into several issues like View not supported.

```
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 166 (CommandNotSupportedOnView): 'Namespace aiops.hostView is a view, not a collection' on server 192.168.20.166:30011. The full response is {​​​​​​​"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "Namespace aiops.hostView is a view, not a collection", "code": 166, "codeName": "CommandNotSupportedOnView"}​​​​​​​
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:175)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:303)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:259)
```

Does Spring support MongoDB views out of the box? any example will greatly help!

Thank you in advance

Comment: excuse me but how did you create the view manually or by coding with spring boot ? 
I tried to do that using mongoTemlate and I didn't succeed 
I used mongoTemplate.executeCommand(create: "viewName" , viewOwn: "source" , pipeline : [ pip  ] ) 
I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is somewhat old, but I will leave my solution in case someone stumbles on this, like I did.

As far as I know, you can't use the usual Spring Data approach: you can't annotate an Entity with the `@Document(value="YOUR_VIEW_NAME")` annotation and create a related repository extending the MongoRepository class.

But you can query the view directly from the [MongoTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo-template), passing along the name of your view.

Let's say you have a User entity defined like this:

```java
public class User {
    @Id
    String id;

    String name;
}
```

Then you can map it to the documents of a view named "userview", and query it like this:

```java
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("name").is("Bob"));

// template is an object of class MongoTemplate that you can inject or autowire
List<User> users = template.find(query, User.class, "userview");
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently faced the same problem, what @gere said is not entirely correct, you can use a view with spring data repositories but there are some limitations that are related to the limitation of the view itself.

In my case, the problem was that I was using annotation CompositeIndex and Indexed on the document which represents a view, and as MongoDB view uses the underlying collection indexes so it does not have the operation command to create an index for itself and when spring data tries to create an index on that view, MongoDB throws an exception. After removing those annotations, I was able to use them via my repository. I would suggest you use a read-only repository as well to prevent having a save method or delete as I think that is a view limitation too. if you search you can find examples of read-only repositories.

In your case, you need to find what operation you were trying to do on a normal collection that view does not support.

Comment: Thank you @navid_gh!!